# Question Regarding Linux Kernel Pagetable

Tags: linux-kernel, arm

I'm currently working on linux kernel boot on ARM A-78 cpu. And I am using linux kernel version 5.10.39.

So, My question is regarding linux kernel pagetable.

How we can change pagetable entry of linux kernel according to system RAM??

Comment: Question unclear. Are you asking how the system handles paging when there is a limited amount of memory?

Comment: Hii Sagar, Right .. I'm asking about it ...